# Bluetooth headset kills other audio?

Tags: bluetooth, audio, htc-evo, bluetooth-hsp, bluetooth-audio

I have a bluetooth headset for voice calls on my HTC EVO 4G. When I connect it, voice calls work well, and other audio works *before* I try pressing the "call" button on the headset.

The first time I press this button, the built-in voice recognition cuts out. After that, it works fine, but no more audio will be routed through either the speaker or the audio jack on the phone, and although the headset still works for voice calls, it is stuck to that stupid "*BT profile*", so it dosen't get the audio for music and such.

A few notes

- this **only** happens with the headset, no other bluetooth device (such as keyboard), but I have not tested it with a bluetooth sound system.
- this does not occur with any other audio connection, i.e. headphones etc.
- switching sound modes (vibrate, loud, silent) has no effect
- the only solution I have now is resetting the phone, which I would love not to have to do every time I use my  headset

I am running Cyanogenmod 7.1 (stable). Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround or a patch?